# Clean up of calendar event before/during duplication

Tags: applescript, calendar, ical

This issue all stems from duplicating events from subscribed calendars to a single iCloud calendar I share with someone. When the origin calendar is well structured everything works as expected. My Applescript duplicates the event, and on subsequent runs the duplicate action even updates any changed info in the events (I assume it sees a matching `UID` and modifies the event instead of recreating it).

I currently have a calendar that sets it's `UID` to a full blown URL (it also originally had an issue with timezones I remedied, it's why the `duplicate` includes the start and end dates). This creates issues with duplicating, I believe, because the new events have their `UID`'s have some characters stripped/replaced (`/`,`:`) and they stop matching up.

```
http://domain.com/folder/page.php?eventid=3675 becomes  
http__domain_com_folder_page.php?eventid=3675
```

First thought was to use a regular expression via sed to create a more standard `UID`...

```
repeat with theEvent in theEventsList

    tell theEvent

        ...

        set oldUID to the uid

        set theCommandString to "echo \"" & oldUID & "\" | sed 's:http\\://\\([a-z.]*\\)/\\([a-z0-9]*\\)/[a-z.]*\\?\\([a-z]*\\)\\=\\([0-9]*\\):\\2-\\3\\4@\\1:'" as string

        set newUID to do shell script theCommandString

        ...

    end tell

end repeat
```

The result is, `folder-eventid3675@domain.com`. But now I'm stuck. `Duplicate`, nor `make`, seems to want to let me create a new event where I include `uid` in the properties.

```
make new event at end of calendar sportsCalendar with properties {start date:startTime, end date:endTime, uid:newUID, url:passURL, description:passDescription, summary:passSummary, location:passLocation}
```

-

```
duplicate theEvent to end of calendar sportsCalendar with properties {start date:startTime, end date:endTime, uid:newUID}
```

Both give AppleEvent handler failed, error -10000. At this point I've tried so many variations I'm kinda lost.

At one point I tried setting the original `UID` to my generated one. And that resulted in a different error, -10006...

```
Calendar got an error: Can’t set uid of event to "folder-eventid3675@domain.com".
```

I can live without some of this stuff, but at this point I'm really just curious what I'm doing wrong. Is there any way to *fix* the UID *and* duplicate an event from one calendar to another? Thanks!

**Edit:**
Updating the sed command to be a little cleaner. Sadly it still requires double escaping for a bunch of pieces.
Also adding a bit more code to show how things are constructed.

Comment: I know it's a somewhat common syntax, but using slashes in sed makes the command far longer than it has to be in many common scenarios due to having to escape all the slashes in a path or URL. Semicolons are preferable.

Comment: Thanks @Froggard, I'll keep that in mind and try to clear up the syntax a bit. Luckily that doesn't seem to be what's causing issues.